# Convert objects into queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Probably, it is a bad and db expensive idea, but is there a way to convert list of objects back to a queryset?

```py
foo_list = [foo1, foo2, foo3, ...]
```

something like: `foo_qs = queryset(foo_list)`

So that i can return paginated queryset??

**Edited**

So far . . .

```
id_list = [foo.id for foo in foo_list]
foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(user__id__in=id_list)
```

Comment: I think what you have tried so far should work. Could you please tell us the problem with your approach.

Comment: makes additional queries just as much as the length of unique elements in id_list, for duplicate elements, it uses cache I guess

Comment: `unique_ id_list = list(set(str(id_list)))` with this you can remove the duplicate elements from the list and then pass it to the queryset.  `foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(user__id__in=unique_ id_list)`

Comment: If your are looking for pagination then in that case you can refer to the DRF documentation here `https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/`.

Comment: duplicates dont make any difference in this case (no additional db quries )since they are already cached. what I meant was that there's additional db query for each element in id_list. Since I already have the objects, I was hoping for a way to turn them back into queryset without making any query to db or atleast very minimum query.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(user__id__in=[foo.id for foo in foo_list])
```